# Mocking a method that takes a mocked parameter object in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

The to be tested method

```
public  string GetPopulatedField(string input)
{
    IParameterCollection sqlParams = CreateParameterCollection();
    sqlParams.Add("param", input);
    string recordCollection = DataAccess.ExecuteSelect(SQL, ref sqlParams);
    return recordCollection ;
}
```

The test method

```
public void Test()
{
    // Mocking one of the dependencies used by the ExecuteSelect
    MockHelper.CreateAndRegisterMock<IParameterCollection>();
  
    Mock<Access> mock = new Mock<Access>();
    //mocking the ExecuteSelect Method that takes a string and and IParameterCollection
    mock.Setup(t => t.ExecuteSelect(It.IsAny<string>(),ref It.Ref<IParameterCollection>.IsAny)).Returns("123");

    //The execute Select is called from the GetPopulatedField method
    var x= MockHelper.CreateAndRegisterMock<PopulateField>("Container");
    Assert.AreEqual("123", x.Object.GetPopulatedField("value"));
}
```

The issue is when `ExecuteSelect` is called from `GetPopulateField` it is using the Mock object and not the actual `IParameterCollection`, so what is the correct way to Mock the `ExecuteSelect` properly?

`ref It.Ref<IParameterCollection>.IsAny` I believe this should be changed to reflect the mocked one.

Comment: Could you please share with us that code that you want to cover with test(s)?

Comment: @PeterCsala I added the Get PopulatedField method.

Comment: Is this `DataAccess` injected into the class?

Comment: By the way what is this `return string;`?

Comment: @PeterCsala fixed that, also yes. it's actually Data.DataAccess but I don't have access to the implementation    
`public sealed class Data{ public static IDataAccess DataAccess { get; }`

Comment: Well if it is `static` then you are not injecting it via a DI during object creation. If you want to mock that dependency then you need to provide that via constructor or property injection.

Comment: @PeterCsala I have no control on the `ExecuteSelect` I can only do changes to the `GetPopulatedField`

Comment: What is ` MockHelper.CreateAndRegisterMock<IParameterCollection>();`? Can you please share the code or ideally full [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @GuruStron I don't have access to the implementation of that,`public interface IParameterCollection : IList<IParameter>, ICollection<IParameter>, IEnumerable<IParameter>, IEnumerable`

Comment: If you want to test the GetPopulatedField method you should not run it on a Mock of PopulateField but on an actual instance so x should be `new PopulateField()` instead. Your dependencies like Access should be passed trough via constructor or property injection. The code shown is not complete enough to help with that.

Comment: `MockHelper.CreateAndRegisterMock` what does this do

Comment: Your question is completely incomprehensible. Impossible to reproduce it from the presented pieces of code. / Moq is constrained isolating framework. It allows you to mock only virtual methods. Probably your task is to mock non-virtual methods. This can be done using unconstrained frameworks such as TypeMock, JustMock, MS Fakes, Prig, Ionad.Fody, Pose, Harmony, MethodRedirect. / If you edit the question by adding code that can be copied and compiled, then I can probably provide an example of unconstrained features. / But it is better, to rewrite the code so that it uses dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

In a unit test, it is important to only test a unit, a small portion of code. The smaller the unit,

- the easier the reason can be found if a failure occurs.
- the faster the tests can be run.

In order to reduce the code to the relevant unit, two aspects are important:

- you want to test the real code of the unit as it would be used in the program flow - hence you create a real instance of the class you want to test, not a mock.
- you do not want to test code that the unit depends on - therefore

  - you structure your code in a way that you can replace dependencies with mocks and
  - you create mocks for the dependencies when testing.

With that in mind, you could change your `PopulateField` class like this:

```
public class PopulateField
{
  private readonly IDataAccess _dataAccess; 

  public PopulateField(IDataAccess dataAccess)
  {
    _dataAccess = dataAccess;
  }

  public  string GetPopulatedField(string input)
  {
    IParameterCollection sqlParams = CreateParameterCollection();
    sqlParams.Add("param", input);
    string recordCollection = _dataAccess.ExecuteSelect(SQL, ref sqlParams);
    return recordCollection;
  }

  // ...
}
```

With an instance of type `IDataAccess` injected into the constructor and used in the `GetPopulatedFields` method, you can easily replace it with a mock in the tests:

```
public void Test()
{
    // Create a mock for the data access
    Mock<IDataAccess> mockDataAccess = new Mock<IDataAccess>();
    //mocking the ExecuteSelect Method that takes a string and and IParameterCollection
    mockDataAccess.Setup(t => t.ExecuteSelect(It.IsAny<string>(),ref It.Ref<IParameterCollection>.IsAny())).Returns("123");

    // Create an instance of PopulateFields so the tests run on real code
    var pf = new PopulateFields(mockDataAccess.Object);
    var actual = pf.GetPopulatedFields("input");
    Assert.AreEqual("123", actual);
}
```

Please note that the creation of the `IParameterCollection` happens in a method of `PopulateFields` that you cannot replace with this behavior. There are two ways to go about this:

1. If it is important to also mock the instantiation of the ParameterCollection, you need to create a factory interface that contains a method that returns the `IParameterCollection` instance. Along with `IDataAccess` an instance implementing this interface is also injected into the constructor of `PopulateFields` so you can replace it with a mock when testing.
2. If you only want to validate that the correct parameters are set when `GetPopulatedFields` is called, you can add a validation to the setup. Unfortunately, for `It.Ref<T>` there is only a `IsAny` and no `Is` method that allows deciding whether the parameters match, so we solve it with a callback:

```
mock.Setup(t => t.ExecuteSelect(It.IsAny<string>(),ref It.Ref<IParameterCollection>.IsAny)).Callback((string s, ref IParameterCollection params) => {
  if (!params.Contains("param")) // Adjust conditions to IParameterCollection
    throw new ApplicationException("Parameter was not added");
}.Returns("123");
```